# Disabling My Public Pages feature in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 CE.

How can i disable add,manage and edit control (Dockbar) of a user's "My Public Pages" and "My Private Pages"?

Please find me some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

http://vir-liferay.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-configure-dockbar-based-on-roles.html

this works for me....I fix it

Answer (score 1):

try this thing. write this code in your **portal-ext.properties**

```
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.public.layouts.modifiable=false
layout.user.public.layouts.auto.create=false
```

similarly you found other options also.

Comment: your code removes the my public page option in the  GOTO of dockbar,thanks.but how can i remove the entire dockbar for users other than administrator.

Comment: u can do that in theme...where u need to check permission

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I looked for disable access to public and private pages.
The solution is to add these lines in your portal-ext.properties :

To disable access to private pages :

```
layout.user.private.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.private.layouts.modifiable=false
layout.user.private.layouts.auto.create=false
```

to disable public pages :

```
layout.user.public.layouts.enabled=false
layout.user.public.layouts.modifiable=false
layout.user.public.layouts.auto.create=false
```

P.S : That's disable also the access to default portlets (Directory user list)
http://yoursite/web/yourusername/home

http://yoursite/user/yourusername/home